# Excel Formula to Pull Most Recent Data if Dates are Sequential

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sequential

I have a workbook containing `SSNs` and `Coverage Dates`. Most `SSNs` have duplicate rows where the coverage dates are sequential. They end coverage on one row then begin coverage the day after on the next row.

What formula can I use that pulls the most recent **Coverage End Date** so I can consolidate these data rows into only one necessary row if all of the dates are sequential?

Below is an example of what my workbook looks like:

[image]

Comment: `MAXIF()` or `MAXIFS()` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try `MAXIF()`.

```
=MAXIFS($D$2:$D$8,$A$2:$A$8,G2)
```

***M365*** dynamic formula-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A8),MAXIFS(D2:D8,A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken the **`Coverage End Date`** is the second last column i.e. before the **`Waiver`** Column. If is that is correct, then you could try the following formulas as per your need.

[image]

---

The following formula assumes you have a column of **`UNIQUE`** **`SSN`** and only need the **`Most Recent Coverage End Date`** using <kbd>SORT( )</kbd> & <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> function.

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=@SORT(FILTER($D$1:$D$7,G2=$A$1:$A$7),,-1)
```

---

The above formula needs to be filled down and uses <kbd>@</kbd> which is **`Implicit intersection operator`** used to return a **`single top left value from an array`**, hence while **`exiting`** the **`edit mode`**, you will get a pop up like the below screencap and select **`No`**

[image]

---

However, if you want to return the **`UNIQUE`** **`SSNs`** as well the dates, then use the <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> to spill the whole as a single dynamic array formula.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A1:A7),
     b,MAP(a,LAMBDA(x,@SORT(FILTER(D1:D7,A1:A7=x),,-1))),
     HSTACK(a,b))
```

---

If you need header, then you can make it look fancy by wrapping the formula within a <kbd>VSTACK( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,UNIQUE(A1:A7),
     b,MAP(a,LAMBDA(x,@SORT(FILTER(D1:D7,A1:A7=x),,-1))),
     c,{"SSN","End Coverage Date"},
     VSTACK(c,HSTACK(a,b)))
```

---

**Update: Since OP commented as below --**

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,FILTER(C2:D8,G2=A2:A8),
     b,DROP(a,1,-1),
     c,DROP(a,,1),
     TOROW(DROP(FILTER(a,IFNA(IF(b-c=1,0,1),1)),,1)))
```

---

The above formula only needs to filled down, as it is going to spill on right!.

---

You can do a dynamic spill array formula to return all the data at once.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A8,
     b,C2:D8,
     ua,UNIQUE(a),
     c,DROP(b,1,-1),
     d,DROP(b,,1),
     e,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",ua,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,
            TOROW(FILTER(d,(IFNA(IF(c-d=1,0,1),1))*
            (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(a,y)))>0))))),""),1),
       HSTACK(ua,e))
```

---

You can also use delimiter for the multiple end coverage data to show:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A8,
     b,C2:D8,
     ua,UNIQUE(a),
     c,DROP(b,1,-1),
     d,DROP(b,,1),
     e,DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",ua,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,
            TEXTJOIN(" | ",,TEXT(FILTER(d,(IFNA(IF(c-d=1,0,1),1))*
            (ISNUMBER(XMATCH(a,y)))>0),"m/d/yyyy"))))),""),1),
     VSTACK({"SSN","End Coverage Date"},HSTACK(ua,e)))
```

---

Or more easy way:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G7</kbd>

```
=VSTACK({"SSN","End Coverage Date"},
  CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A2:E8,(IFNA(IF(
  DROP(C2:D8,1,-1)-DROP(C2:D8,,1)=1,0,1),1))*
  (XMATCH(A2:A8,UNIQUE(A2:A8)))),1,4))
```

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you, I am able to pull the latest coverage end date. But what happens when there is a break in coverage? Look at the 987-65-4321 record in Rows 2 and 3. They end coverage on 3-31-22 but then pick it back up on 5-1. So we should be pulling in their 3-31 and 12-31 CED. Is there a way to grab both?

Comment: @JennaTerral so will it happen for other `SSN` also? And will there be any such instances where it can thrice or more than that

Comment: Yes it could happen for other SSNs. I just gave you a sample because the worksheet I have is 28,000 records long. It could also happen more than once

Comment: Way over-complex.

Comment: @zsalya if you have any easy way then post it, also I have posted the easy way, and the solution on which you voted is absolutely wrong from beginning, because OP needed the end coverage, while solution given for Start Date Coverage, which means the person was not able to understand the question, secondly OP's requirement is different where in that solution anyway wont work

Comment: @JennaTerral are you able to follow the solutions. I have updated the answers as per the latest update you have given

Answer (score 0):

maxif() per @Harun24hr is quick, but do I detect also a requirement to identify gaps in the date ranges as well?

If so, add a column E, putting in E3 `=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3=B2),C3-D2,0)` and drag down.
[image]

Then use a Pivot Table with three Value fields:
min(Start)
max(End)
max(Gap)
All codes/products which have contiguous periods will show 1 in that column and those with gaps will show the largest gap.
[image]

P.S. The purpose of the IF..AND is to not mix up dates from separate codes/products.

Comment: Your answer is wrong: For `987-65-4321` the output should be `3/31/23` & `12/31/23` and by your logic it will return two max dates for `111-12-1234` which is wrong. Flawed solution